# No definition of Sum in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, razor, nopcommerce

I have written following code in which I want to calculate total sum of the price.
But it says no definition of sum. What possibly might be wrong?

```
public virtual IList<DesignWiseTotal> summary(int customerId)
    {
        var query = _orderItemRepository.Table;

        return query.Where(oi => oi.Product.Designer_Id == customerId)
                        .Select(oi => new DesignWiseTotal
                        {
                            GrandTotal = oi.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                        });
    }
```

Above code is quite similar to following code, which works fine. Following code calculates sum group by twine. What I am trying to do in above code is calculate the grand total of all twines for one customer.

```
 public virtual IList<DesignWiseTotal> DesignWiseSplits(int customerId)
    {
        var query = _orderItemRepository.Table;

        return query.Where(oi => oi.Product.Designer_Id == customerId)
                        .GroupBy(oi => oi.Product.Twine)
                        .Select(oi => new DesignWiseTotal
                        {
                            Total = oi.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                            Twine = oi.Key,
                            }).ToList();
    }
```

I am attaching a screenshot of error too.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Whst is `Table`-property of your `orderItemRepository`?

Comment: I am using nopcommerce. Its nopcommerce syntax to access table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `OrderItem` (or whatever the name of the class obtained is from the repository) isn't a collection (e.g. `IEnumerable`, `IQueryable` etc) , so `.Sum` cannot be applied.

In the second query, you are Summing the `Groups` of `.GroupBy(oi => oi.Product.Twine)`. Each group will have one or more elements, hence `Sum` is permissable

The choice of lambda parameter name is unfortunate .. more clear would be:

```
.GroupBy(oi => oi.Product.Twine)
.Select(grp => new DesignWiseTotal ...
```

Since it appears you want to return a simple scalar value (Grand Total), why not change the method signature to:

```
public virtual decimal DesignWiseSplits(int customerId)
```

And then

```
return query.Where(oi => oi.Product.Designer_Id == customerId)
            .Sum(oi => oi.PriceExclTax);
```

(or I guess return a single `DesignWiseTotal` with the Sum for the filtered customer`?)

(And I'm hoping of course that `oi.PriceExclTax` is decimal)

**Edit**

If you retain this signature:

```
public virtual IList<DesignWiseTotal> summary(int customerId)
```

You'll can use:

```
return new List<DesignWiseTotal>
{  
   new DesignWiseTotal
   {
       GrandTotal = query.Where(oi => oi.Product.Designer_Id == customerId)
                         .Sum(oi => oi.PriceExclTax);
   }
};
```

Although this does seem overkill to return a scalar as an array of a class.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed solution. Please tell me one more thing. I want to store this sum in a variable called GrandTotal. Howto do it?

Comment: instead of `return query.Where(...` replace this with `var GrandTotal = query.Where(...`

Comment: actually there is another problem. i was populating a variable GrandTotal of DesignWiseTotal Class. But since select statement is not being used now. How do i do it?

Comment: I've udpated with an Edit.